# Cannot figure out how to get Pascal Triangle In Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to get this series

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
```

NOTE:The spaces mentioned have to be present it should have the exact same output as i have mentioned
I tried this:

```
class pattern_19
{
 static void main()
 {
     int i,j;
     int s=1;
     System.out.println(s);
     for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
     {
         for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
         {
             s=s*11;
            }
            System.out.println(s);
            s=1;
        }
    }
}
MY OUTPUT:
11
121
1331
14641
161051
1771561
```

This did not work any help will be appreciated

Comment: "*This did not work*" is quite vague: what output did you get? What was wrong about it?

Comment: You just got an assignment to "draw this triangle"? The task didn't mention the name of this triangle? It's a very well-known construct.

Comment: Here is some useful resource about [Array Exercises](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/)

Comment: Sorry guys its a pascal triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would not compile because your main method was not defined correctly. This is one thing but not the main reason why you were getting an unexpected output.

---

Your `s` variable represent one integer on each line.

What you'll have to do from there is split your `int` and print each one of the digits seperately.

---

Here is a correction, I used an enhanced loop and a charArray to print the digits seperately but there are other ways to achieve this of course (using a loop and integer division works also or modify the way you find `s`).

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i, j;
  int s = 1;
  System.out.println(s + " ");
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        s = s * 11;
    }
    for (char c : String.valueOf(s).toCharArray()) System.out.print(c + " ");
    System.out.println();
    s = 1;
  }
}
```

PS : Multiplying by 11 wont work when you'll need numbers with a length of 2. I'll edit my answer right now.

### Here is the algorithm solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int rows = 6;
  int[][] triangle = new int[rows][rows];

  for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (j == 0) triangle[i - 1][j] = 1;
      else triangle[i - 1][j] = triangle[i - 2][j - 1] + triangle[i - 2][j];
      System.out.print(triangle[i - 1][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally also got an alternative to do the same here it goes

```
public class PascalTriangle {
    public static void main() {
        int rows = 6;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            int number = 1;
            System.out.format("%" + (rows - i) * 2 + "s", "");
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.format("%4d", number);
                number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this one is working properly .[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of your code. Images can get deleted and links can go stale. Instead, copy the code from your IDE and paste it into the question. Click the "edit" link under the text of your answer to make changes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer with code, attached the code. Even if the code works and the link is not deleted, it is useless if somebody find that one useless as he will need to type it.